# Problema com pesquisa e url amigável

Tags: php, htaccess

Boa noite,

Tenho uma pesquisa que está a funcionar bem, só estou agora a ter um problema quando alguém escreve uma palavra com acento ou duas palavras separadas por espaço, quebra-me a url.

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver esta situação?

**Código**

```
 <form method="post" id="form" action="">
          <div style="margin-left:150px;">
              <div style="float:left; width:500px;"><input style="height: 38px;" id="valor_pesquisa" name="valor_pesquisa" type="text" placeholder="Restaurantes, bares, hotéis..." /></div>
              <div style="float:left; margin-left:5px;"><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" /></div>
          </div> 
        </form>
        <script>
          $(function() {
              $("#form").submit(function(e) {
                  if($('#valor_pesquisa').val() === ''){
                      $("#form").attr("action", "http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/todos");
                  }else{
                    var valor_pesquisa = $("#valor_pesquisa").val();
                    $("#form").attr("action", "http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/"+valor_pesquisa);
                  }
              });
          });
        </script>
```

**.htaccess**

```
# Rota Pesquisa
RewriteRule ^locais/pesquisa/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$  index.php?controller=pesquisa&option=pesquisa&pesquisa=$1
```

**Actual**

```
RewriteRule ^locais/pesquisa/([\p{L}\p{N}\s_-]+)$  index.php?controller=pesquisa&option=pesquisa&pesquisa=$1
```

Comment: Da internal server error se tirar o esapaco que tem no regex ja abre o site se tiver o espaco da internal server error

Comment: Funciona os espacos mas acentos nao coloquei acima no actual como esta

Answer (score 1):

Bem acabei resolvendo o meu problema com a seguinte `regex` para que precisar.

```
RewriteRule ^locais/pesquisa/([A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÒÖÚÇÑ\s_-]+$)$  index.php?controller=pesquisa&option=pesquisa&pesquisa=$1
```

Claro com ajudas de todas as resposta aqui dadas obrigado a todos

Comment: e se a pesquisa conter numeros?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você possa incluir outros intervalos na RegEx para permitir caracteres com acentos, tipo `[À-üa-zA-Z0-9 _-]+`

Comment: Com essa já aceita os acentos mas espaços não

Answer (score -1):

`var valor_pesquisa = window.encodeURIComponent($("#valor_pesquisa").val());`

Comment: testei dessa forma mas quebra a url igual retorna para a pagina de erro